# pass value from template to view in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am new to django.I need to send id of clicked button to my function `pdf_view` that pdf view use id of that button for filtering and returning some data.

Here is my template :

(regions[i].id is a number between 1 to 10, it is the thing that I need to send to views.py)

```
<h5 class="card-title">regions[i].id </h5>
<a href="{% url 'app:pdf-data' %}"> export pdf </a>
```

part of views.py:

```
def pdf_view(request):
reg = **********************here i need to get region from template***********************
data = Model.objects.filter(region=reg)
context = {'data':data }
```

If I put region equal to a number , every thing goes well.I just need to get region from template.Please help me with this problem.

Comment: is `regions[i].id` a javascript variable?

Comment: @rollingthedice yes it is,I've cut a part of my js code to display here.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your view accept an url parameter with default value. (**[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments)**)

So for instance:

**urls**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('my-path/', views.pdf_view, name="pdf-data"),
    path('my-path/<region>/', views.pdf_view, name="pdf-data-export"),
]
```

**views**

```py
def pdf_view(request, region=False):
    if region:
        # do something with region

    data = Model.objects.filter(region=reg)
    context = {'data':data }
```

**html**
Since you can't actually pass the variable within django template's `{% url %}` tag, you will need to build the url manually.

So instead of

```html
<a href="{% url 'app:pdf-data-export' region=some_region_id %}"> export pdf </a>
```

You have to reverse the url and then concat the url parameter:

```html
<a href="{% url 'app:pdf-data' %}"+ region[i].id +"/"> export pdf </a>
```

Comment: But again i don't have region value.you made region as a boolean but i need to get the region number and use it in : `data = Model.objects.filter(region=reg)` instead of reg.(reg is equal to **regions[i].id** and i just need that)

Comment: `<a href="{% url 'app:pdf-data' %}"+ region[i].id +"/"> export pdf </a>` will create you a url with region as url parameter.  

So it will be `my-path/5` presuming `region[i].id` is 5.  And when you call the view with url parameter, region will be `5` instead of `False`.